# How to Move Weekly Files with Timestamp to Network Drive (Sharepoint Folder)

Tags: python, pandas

I've generated some results, wrote to csv and appended a now timestamp to it:

```
df.to_csv("results.csv", index=False)
os.rename("results.csv", time.strftime("results_" + "%Y%m%d%H%M.csv"))
```

So now I have a file - **results_201908061552**

Previously without the timestamp, I'd use the below code to move to Sharepoint folder in my network drive:

```
shutil.copy('results.csv','//teamsharepoint.abc.com/Folder/results.csv')
```

But considering I'll be running the codes (with timestamp) weekly, how do I move the file to the Sharepoint folder in my network drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to match file names (using a wildcard). This will move all the files starting with 'results' and ending with the '.csv' extension.

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('results*.csv'):
    print(file)
    shutil.copy(file,'//teamsharepoint.abc.com/Folder/')
```

Comment: A folder will contain the results, each differenciated by the timestamps. If I'm running for week 7, how will it retrieve the latest result file?